# Tiles vs. JSP includes

Tags: jsp, tiles, include

We have a large web-app with hundreds of jsps pages. To avoid repeating markup up blocks we are considering making use of apache tiles. Now it seems messy to have a combination of both

```
<t:insertTemplate template="/WEB-INF/templates/xxxxx.jsp">
```

and

```
<%@ include file="xxxxx.jsp"%>
```

statements so we are considering converting all includes statements to insertTemplates (whether or not the template includes any tile syntax)

Has anyone had any experience with using tiles 100% for jsp includes?

Comment: check this http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2002/jw-0104-tilestrut.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do so. The major difference is however that `@include` directive is compiletime (thus, happens only once during startup) and that `<whatever:include>` tag is runtime (thus, happens on every request). For the case you didn't know that, JSP already offers `<jsp:include>` out the box for this.

It must now be obvious that the tag may be a performance hit when unnecessarily used.